# Get root namespace (assembly namespace) of loaded assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm using the `GetTypeInfo()` method to get the `TypeInfo` of a class from an assembly.

Through that I'm trying to get the root namespace of that assembly (or is it called assembly namespace?). But I can't find a property in there that gives me that namespace. There is `AssemblyQualifiedName` which is a `string` that has the root namespace in it. But there are also a lot of other things in there like version number etc.

How can I get the root namespace of an assembly in .NET Core?

Comment: Why can't you use AssemblyQualifiedName?

Comment: @Crowcoder There is too much info in there, like culture info, assembly version, publicKey etc. I'd have create a regex to get it out. I'm sure there is a property in there to get the actual name as well. I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: Looks like `TypeInfo` has a `Namespace` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assemblies don't have namespaces themselves only the types within the assembly. The thing you could be thinking of is the "Assembly Name", that is often the same name as the "Default Namespace" which most types within the assembly will use.

```
Assembly assembly = //..
string name = assembly.GetName().Name;
```

The `GetName()` returns a [`AssemblyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyname?view=netstandard-1.4) object that contains the pieces that are used to build up the `AssemblyQualifiedName`. This function is available in [.Net Standard 1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getname?view=netstandard-1.0) so is available on [all versions of .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getname?view=netcore-1.0)

Comment: anyway to get all possible assemblies based on a namespace?

Answer (score 0):

As assembly could have multiple namespaces, you only could try to get namespaces of all types:

`.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetTypes().Select(t => t.Namespace).Distinct();`

Comment: hi, given the namespace, how can I get all asemblies with it?